# DELETE multiple tables based on a query result

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, sql-delete

Our database didn't implement `ON DELETE CASCADE` so I need to create a script or a stored procedure to delete records in multiple tables given the results of Ids in a QUery:

I tried it in stored procedure but I cannot assign multiple rows in a variable:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Delete_card`(IN _status INT)
BEGIN

    SET @IDs = SELECT ID FROM TABLE_ID WHERE Status=_status;
    
    DELETE FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID IN (@IDs);
    DELETE FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID IN (@IDs);
    DELETE FROM TABLE_C WHERE ID IN (@IDs);
    DELETE FROM TABLE_D WHERE ID IN (@IDs);
    DELETE FROM TABLE_E WHERE ID IN (@IDs);
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a multi-table DELETE statement:

```
DELETE a, b, c
FROM TABLE_ID t
LEFT JOIN TABLE_A a ON a.id = t.id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.id = t.id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_C c ON c.id = t.id
..................................
WHERE t.Status = ?;
```

Change `?` with the Status value that you want.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fc827af6e99190fc0cdc8c500263309f).

Comment: how about 

.....
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_ID WHERE Status=_status AND <some_complext_where>) 

is this possible?

Comment: @daniel.chan you can use any subquery that satisfies the conditions that you want.